# how to touch UIImageView, then replace with another UIImageView, which drags when finger moves, without lifting finger

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

1. `UIImageView` displayed in `UITableViewCell`
2. user touches `UIImageView`
3. a new UIImageView is displayed on top of it (to be dragged BEYOND `UITableView`)
4. then, WITHOUT LIFTING FINGER, user begins to drag new `UIImageView`
5. touchesMoved then handles moving new UIImageView beyond `UITableView`

My problem is that user has to touch 1st `UIImageView`, then lift finger and touch again to drag.

How can UIImageView created by UITableView delegate cellForRowAtIndexPath() be dragged outside of the UITableView so that eventual touchesended delegate fires?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about moving the original view and adding a new view in the same place as the original? Be sure to add the new view behind the original.